# Tools to distinguish semi-direct product from direct product

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, topological-groups

Suppose we have two topological groups $A$ and $B$ for which we can construct $A\rtimes B$. As a topological space it is homeomorphic to $A\times B$, so we cannot use topological invariant (e.g. homotopy groups, homology etc.) to distinguish them. My question is : What are the most useful algebraic invariants which can distinguish these two object ? Or maybe not "purely" algebraic but using also notion of homological algebra, i.e. group cohomology, algebraic $K$-theory etc. I'm looking for such tools which are applicable in as general cases as possible, so I care about lemma that says  "$A\rtimes B$ is isomorphic to $A\times B$ as topological groups iff *some invariants* are equal". Is there anything like that ?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ commute …?

Comment: A simple example: if $G$ acts on itself by conjugation, $G\rtimes G$ is isomorphic to $G\times G$ (in this case $A$ and $B$ commute). Anyway the question should first be settled in the discrete case. Also $A\rtimes B$ can be accidentally isomorphic to $A\times B$... so it's better to first consider isomorphisms $A\rtimes B\to A\times B$ that are identity on $A$ (and then we can assume it's identity modulo $A$).

Comment: @YCor, isn't $G \rtimes G$ in that case isomorphic to $G \times G$, not just $G$?  I guess I was assuming that we know, not just the abstract group $A \rtimes B$, but also the preferred embeddings $A, B \to A \rtimes B$.

Comment: @LSpice if you like, but then you just solve a 1st year undergraduate exercise...